# STR_TO_DATE в подзапросе

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

Почему не работает такой запрос в `mysql` :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS __temp_orders  
    ( 
      SELECT * FROM orders 
      WHERE STR_TO_DATE(orders.data,'%d.%m.%Y') < '2016-11-01 09:35:00' 
    )
```

Пишет:

> [HY000][1411] Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date

Хотя отдельный подзапрос:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE STR_TO_DATE(orders.data,'%d.%m.%Y') < '2016-11-01 09:35:00'
```

работает прекрасно и возвращает то, из чего я хочу создать таблицу.

Comment: Может temp_orders существует и соответствующее поле в ней типа datetime, а вы то выбираете из БД строку ... может надо вместо `*` явно перечислить требуемые поля, включая применение str_to_date ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании моего интерфейса ко второму запросу неявно добавляется что-то вроде LIMIT 0,100 (чтобы не выводилось на экран всё), и обработка таблицы orders не доходит до записей с пустым полем data, приводящих к ошибке в случае CREATE TABLE.

Добавил в условие data!='' и все работает на ура!

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS __temp_orders  ( SELECT * FROM orders WHERE
>   data!='' AND STR_TO_DATE(data,'%d.%m.%Y') < '2016-11-01 09:35:00' );